# There exists a unique $\mathbb {C}[G] $-submodule of the regular module which is isomorphic to the trivial $\mathbb {C} [G] $-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G $ a finite group. Show that there exists a unique $\mathbb {C}[G] $-submodule of the regular $\mathbb {C}[G] $-module which is isomorphic to the trivial $\mathbb {C} [G] $-module.

How to start?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the module generated by $x=\sum_{g\in G}g$. Show after that if $y$ is fixed by $g$ then there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $y=cx$ (remark that if $g\in G, y=u_1g_1+...+u_ng_n$, $gy$ permutes the coordinates $(c_1,...,c_n)$ of $y$.)

Comment: Thank you! Can you write the proof?